# How do I get the start and end index from a selection inside RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a rich text box that I'm allowing user to highlight text.  Text being loaded is coming from a simple plain text file. But I need to store the absolute start and end character position (relative to beginning of document) of the highlighted text so that when they save it, it can reload with highlights.

So far I can do this to apply the highlighting

```
    private void textBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        HighlightWordInTextBox(this.textBox, this.textBox.Selection.ToString(), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
    }

    public void HighlightWordInTextBox(RichTextBox textbox, string word, SolidColorBrush color)
    {
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(this.textBox.Selection.Start, this.textBox.Selection.End);
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, color);

    }
```

But I do not see anywhere inside the Start or End objects of Selection anything that provides the character position? Almost all the methods return another TextPointer - but how do you get the character position from a TextPointer?

Assuming all the text is loaded into a single

```
   this.textBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(fullText)));
```

**EDIT:**

In the immediate window when debugging I can access something called CharOffset and Offset but cannot do so in the source code, it gives a compile error.  Also those properties although present when inspecting the object at runtime, they are not in the documentation.

[image]

And yet...

[image]

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/rich-text-controls/richtextbox-control/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the index of the Selection's start and end with this...

```
        var docStart = textBox.Document.ContentStart;

        var selectionStart = textBox.Selection.Start;
        var selectionEnd = textBox.Selection.End;

        //these will give you the positions needed to apply highlighting
        var indexStart = docStart.GetOffsetToPosition(selectionStart);
        var indexEnd = docStart.GetOffsetToPosition(selectionEnd);

        //these values will give you the absolute character positions relative to the very beginning of the text.
        TextRange start = new TextRange(docStart, selectionStart);
        TextRange end = new TextRange(docStart, selectionEnd);
        int indexStart_abs = start.Text.Length;
        int indexEnd_abs = end.Text.Length;
```

Comment: why is it minus 2?

Comment: @erotavlas Honestly, I'm not completely sure. But, I tested it multiple times and it was minus 2 for the index.

Comment: I don't think you need the offset of 2.  There are no characters preceding it based on your answer to my other question.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50158510/1462656

Comment: @erotavlas I accepted your edit. Does this now fully answer the question for you?

Comment: Actually this isn't working as expected https://stackoverflow.com/q/50237312/1462656

Comment: @erotavlas Your issue in your other question is probably not related to this. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getoffsettoposition(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation shows very similar code. Try breaking the problem down into simpler code to see if it goes away or you can pinpoint where the issue comes from.

Comment: I know, I think it may be the right way to get the index as seen by the text pointer, but for actual index it is not the correct value that I need to store. I'm still investigating....

Comment: @erotavlas Good luck! At first I found it odd that your text started at index 2, but then I read "Any of the following is considered to be a symbol:
An opening or closing tag for a TextElement element..." in the link. I believe this means the Paragraph and Run are counted as symbols. Perhaps the highlighting produces other TextElements that are being counted in the indexes.

Comment: @erotavlas awesome! I had wondered if the solution might involve TextRanges.