# Why does RichTextBox always contain extra characters before the document start?

Tags: c#, wpf

I start with a blank RichTextBox

```
    <RichTextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="234" Margin="10,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="textBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
    </RichTextBox>
```

And then I load a file, read all text and then add this to the RichTextBox like this

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Text.txt"))
{
    string fullText = sr.ReadToEnd();

    textBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(fullText)));
}
```

When I inspect the fullText that I insert, it looks like this...immediately starts with the character E

[image]

But then after its rendered into the control, I an selecting a part of the beginning of text, but there appear to be a carriage return line feed before the very first character.

[image]

[image]

So my question is does it always insert these characters?

Is there a way to remove this behavior, so it doesn't insert anything before the very first character of the document?

Comment: Just a guess, but you're adding a new paragraph instead of assigning the text value directly.  Perhaps the definition of "paragraph" is "starts with a newline or two"?

Comment: Also, are you *sure* there are no unprintable or special characters before that "E"?

Comment: @BradleyUffner yeah I checked it in notepad++, there's nothing before it.  I think its correct about the paragraph causing this, but not sure how to get around this yet for the first block of text.

Comment: @erotavlas What happens when you use AppendText instead of Document.Blocks.Add?

Comment: If you do `Run r = new Run(fullText);` then `string s = r.Text;` you can see that there is no new line in this, but one is added once you use paragraph

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I tried that, but it treats each line ending (\r\n) as a new paragraph so when it renders in the control, it looks like doubled spaced line, I supposed if  don't care about paragraphs I could just replace all \r\n with \r before appendingtext

Comment: If I put `textbox.Document.Blocks.Clear();` before adding a new paragraph, then I don't get space above. Does this work for you?

Comment: @BlakeThingstadinteresting, yes that's interesting, seems like there is an initial block there by default when I check the count `textBox.Document.Blocks.Count`, and clearing it first solves the issue. Thanks you might want to add this as the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RichTextBox has a Block already in it.
You can remove it with `textbox.Document.Blocks.Clear();`.
Your first new paragraph will now not have space above it.
Paragraphs add space above themselves if they come after another element.